# Paypal SDK redirect URL working on lcoalhost but as soon as i change URL to heroku URL it does not work(node.js and heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My paypal routes

```
app.post('/pay' ,  paymentController.payment)
app.get('/success' ,  paymentController.success)
app.get('/cancel' ,  paymentController.cancel)
```

This is my paymentController

```
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const Cart = require('../models/cart');
const util = require('util');

paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
    'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
});

exports.payment=(req, res)=>{
    const body=req.body
    let cart =  new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {})
    let products=cart.generateArray()

    let items=[]
    let price=0
    products.map(function(elem){
        if (elem instanceof Object){
            const item={
                "name": elem.item.product_name,
                "sku": elem.item._id,
                "price": parseFloat(elem.price),
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": parseInt(elem.qty)
            }
            items.push(item)
            price=parseFloat(price) + (parseFloat(elem.price) * parseInt(elem.qty))
        }
    })
    req.session.price=price     //put total in session to use it in success

    const total=parseFloat(price)+parseInt(10)
    const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            // "return": "thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com/success",
            // "cancel_url": "thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com/cancel"
            "return_url": process.env.APP_URL+"/success",
            "cancel_url": process.env.APP_URL+"/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": items
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": total,
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": price,
                    "tax": 0,
                    "shipping": 10.00
                }
            },
            "description": "Ecommerce web products."
        }]
    }
    //console.log(util.inspect(create_payment_json, false, null, true))

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
                if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
                    res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

exports.success=(req, res)=>{
    const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
    const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

    const execute_payment_json = {
        "payer_id": payerId,
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": req.session.price
            }
        }]
    };

    // Obtains the transaction details from paypal
    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        //When error occurs when due to non-existent transaction, throw an error else log the transaction details in the console then send a Success string reposponse to the user.
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
            res.send('Success');
        }
    });
}

exports.cancel=(req, res)=>{
    res.redirect('/cart');
}
```

This is the .env that contains APP_URL

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

When the code is in this state it works fine but when I change APP_URL to the heroku app url which is this: thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com . It does not work and heroku returns error below

```
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038164+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/controllers/paymentController.js:65
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038172+00:00 app[web.1]: throw error;
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038173+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038173+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038174+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Response Status : 401
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038174+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038175+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038175+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038176+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038176+00:00 app[web.1]: response: {
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038177+00:00 app[web.1]: error: 'invalid_client',
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038177+00:00 app[web.1]: error_description: 'Client Authentication failed',
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038177+00:00 app[web.1]: httpStatusCode: 401
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038178+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038178+00:00 app[web.1]: httpStatusCode: 401
2022-02-01T17:08:18.038178+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-01T17:08:18.042714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/pay" host=thenewerafootwear.herokuapp.com request_id=689af51f-2e7e-4c7a-9a55-1f6e7d879de3 fwd="41.210.16.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=381ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-02-01T17:08:18.171844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
```

> Client Authentication failed

It would appear you need to [configure your heroku environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) (process.env) with the correct CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET constants.

---

Separately, the [v1/payments node sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) you are using is deprecated. Use the current [@paypal/checkout-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk) instead.

---

Additionally, it seems your integration is based on redirects, which is for old websites. For a modern web experience, don't use any redirects. Instead follow the [Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and have two 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML nor redirect). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I will try that method but my client ID and Secret are in the .env but did not post that in the question. But I will try out this method you are talking about